# How to change index names of the output from df.groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, size, rename

I have a pd.series df['target'] and its values are 0 if malignant and 1 if benign. I want to count the number of each value and change the index name to 'malignant' and 'benign' and  which return a Series named target of length 2 with integer values and index = ['malignant', 'benign'] like this;

target 
malignant    212 
benign       357

I tried below

`target = df.groupby(['target']).size()` 
`target.rename(index={'0': 'malignant', '1': 'benign'})`

But it returns below which the index names remain the same.

target 
0     212 
1     357 
dtype: int64

How can I fix it?
Is there a better to have the count value than using .size()?

Comment: You are not redefining the `df` nor passing `inplace=True`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from the fact you are not redefining the dataframe, nor passing the argument `inplace=True`, you can do the replacement first and then use `value_counts()`. Also, keep in mind that if the values are numbers, then `0 != '0'`.

```
output = target.replace({'0': 'malignant', '1': 'benign'}).value_counts()
```

Or, if the values are numerical:

```
output = target.replace({0: 'malignant', 1: 'benign'}).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
target.rename({1: 'malignant', 2: 'benign'}).value_counts() # mapping, changes labels
```